# Does a developer have to write a whole iOS app to make a Siri Shortcut?

Tags: iphone, ios, python, siri

I have some things I'd like to be able to get Siri to do, just on my own iPhone. I could write those things in plain python (possibly in some other language). Can Siri Shortcuts run these (python/other scripts), or would I have to write a whole iOS app?

i.e. the end result would be saying 'Hey Siri, check `<`some very specific, highly personalised thing`>` for me', and Siri runs some python that grabs some data from an API, parses/interprets it, and reads out the result. It could be as simple as that (a bit like a AWS lambda but essentially with voice and done from mobile)

Note: I am in no way an iOS developer nor macOS developer, just a generalist, so I don't know how something like is is built (or even *if* it *can* be built)

Comment: You could install Pythonista which comes with a shortcut to call python scripts.

Comment: @nohillside thanks sounds impressive! I see Pythonista 3 in appstore. Do you know if there are any free ones?

Comment: I never bothered to search further after I fouond Pythonista (and Editorial).

Comment: @nohillside just downloaded scriptable (it’s for javascript). The fact this is all possible is very cool!

Comment: @nohillside I have hit [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61275124/provide-an-argument-from-siri-voice-input-to-scriptable-script) stumbling block. Hopefully there is a solution